# Error Notification--Can anyone tell me what this means?

Tags: field-mapping

- Ages of People: Ages of People: bad value for restricted picklist field: Parents;5-6 years
- Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Ages of People: bad value for restricted picklist field: Parents;5-6 years: [Ages_of_People__c]

Comment: You have a restricted picklist and someone tried to set an unsupported value.

Answer (score 3):

The message means exactly what it says. You're trying to provide a value to a picklist which is restricted- meaning it only allows certain values. The list is specified on the setup page for the field. Trying to provide any other value which is not on the list will result in this error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting on all pick-list fields that will prevent updating/inserting records if the value of the field is not defined:

[image: Sample]

If this is checked the value entered must be defined. If it is unchecked you can enter any undefined value into the picklist. **Please note this setting cannot be turned off for picklists that use global picklist value sets.**

Also note, that this may occur if you are trying to insert a value into a dependent picklist if the value was not permitted by the dependency; [Define Dependent Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US).

Finally, check to make sure the record type permits the picklist. Couldn't figure out the magic words to google to find the official documentation on this peice but basically you navigate through setup>Object Name>Record Types> (Setup>objects>custom object Name> scroll to record types list) once you are on the record type, you should see a list of picklists available for editing.